# CentOS 7 nginx httpd forbidden /var/www

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-403

I tried to configure nginx as revers proxy with apache/httpd on a virtual centOS 7 server. But I always get a 403 error. 
Scenario:
One virtual centos 7 server with two domains (domain1.com and domain2.com). Both domains have different ip-addresses.
domain1.com should serve content from nginx webserver, for now from port 80, later with SSL from 443.
domain2.com should forwarded from nginx to httpd and serve the httpd content, for now from port 8080, later with SSL from port 8443.
php 7.2 installed.

nginx configuration:
domain 1:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

domain2:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    root /var/www/domain2.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain2.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 1200;
        proxy_send_timeout 1200;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|avi|mpeg|mpg|wmv|png|css|js|xml)$ {
        root /var/www/domain2.com/html;
    }

}
```

Default server is commented out in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Configuration of httpd for domain2.com:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    <Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/domain2.com.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">
        # we must declare a (any) parameter in here 
        # or it won't register the proxy ahead of time
        ProxySet disablereuse=off
    </Proxy>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
    </FilesMatch>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domain2.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain2.com/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Port is set to 8080 on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.
SELinux is disabled, for testing.
/var/www/domain1.com/html and /var/www/domain2.com/html owned by root (was default when installed httpd)
and have execution permissions for user, group and others. 
Firewall port 80 and 8080 is open.

The problem is, when I started all services (httpd, nginx, php-fpm), I just get a 403 forbidden error when trying to test domain2.com with any browser. The nginx log says:

```
directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: domain2.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain2.com"
```

Since it is my first time using nginx and revers proxy, I have no idea what went wrong. I've searched on google and tried some solutions, but nothing worked. Can someone tell me where I did an mistake please and how to solve that problem or give a good guide? Would be very thankful.

Comment: The configuration in your question does not look like the configuration that's causing the error. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I didn't know this command. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

With the `nginx -T` I found an hidden config-file for a virtual host. Deleted it and everything worked. Thanks to Richard Smith